# SafeArrayTypeMismatchException using VirtualBox from c#

Tags: c#, virtualbox

I'm using the VirtualBox type library from C# as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using VirtualBox;

namespace ConsoleApplication
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IVirtualBox vbox = new VirtualBoxClass();

            IHost h = vbox.Host;

            Array a = h.USBDevices;           
        }
    }
}
```

The line Array *a = h.USBDevices;* causes a SafeArrayTypeMismatchException. Has anyone else had the same problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126012

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = (IUSBDevice[])h.USBDevices
```